# Patterns about bean management in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I have a `Task` and a `TaskHandler`.

The handler access DB through `DaoService`. The `DaoService` is managed
by Spring Container but the handler is generated by `new`, and not managed by Spring Container.

So I think I can't access the `DaoService` in handler by `Autowired`.

So I tried to pass the `DaoService` to the handler.But I don't know How to pass it.

In my current implements:

1、I set the DaoService to a Task.

```
public Task generateTask(Param param, DaoService dao)
{
    Task task = new Task();
    task.setDao(dao);
    task.setparam(getTaskParam(param));
    return task;
}
```

2、In `Task`'s `call()`, I set the `DaoService` to handler.

```
class Task implements Callable<Boolean>
{
    DaoService dao;
    // getter and setter
    public boolean call()
    {
        TaskHandler handler = TaskHandlerMap.getHandler();
        handler.setDaoService(dao);
        return handler.process(param);
    }
}
```

3、At last, I my `main()` I call the generateTask() to get the task.

```
class MainClass()
{
    @Autowired
    DaoService dao;

    Param param = new Param();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Task task = generateTasks(param, dao);
        // submit the task to thread pool.
    }
}
```

My problem is:

1、`Task` should not contain a member called `DaoService`, `Task` has nothing
to do with `DaoService`, `Task` should only concerns about the `TaskHandler`.

2、`DaoService` should not be passed to `generateTasks()`. One `Task` can be
created even there is no `DaoService`.

How to avoid this? Or some good advice?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated:**

According to @AndyWilkinson advice, the code maybe like this:

```
class TaskHandlerMap
{
    @Autowired
    private static XXXHandler xxxHandler;

    private static Map<String,AbstractItemHandler> map = Maps.newHashMap();

    static
    {
        map.put(Constants.XXX_PATH, xxxHandler);
    }


    public static AbstractItemHandler get(String key)
    {
        return map.get(key);
    }

}
```

But I don't think the static field can be autowired.

Comment: You've managed to eliminate enough of your code that's what left isn't even valid, so it's impossible to tell exactly what you're asking. If your objection is that different kind of tasks need different dependencies and that you don't want to explicitly pass around a DAO to all tasks, then you're probably wanting an Abstract Factory.

Comment: @chrylis I'm sorry, I didn't describe my question clearly, I updated the question and hope you can understand me.

Comment: You still can't autowire method variables.

Comment: @chrylis I'm so sorry, It's my mistake, I have corrected it.

Comment: Does TaskHandlerMap.getHandler() have to be a static method? If not, you could use Spring to create a single TaskHandlerMap instance that has DaoService injected into it. Then, whenever TaskHandlerMap creates a TaskHandler, it can pass DaoService into it.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I wanted to create the TaskHandlerMap using Spring, but I don't want to hard code the map.  I think it maybe like that. I updated in the question.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I updated the question, I don't know how to do that. Hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use static methods or fields on `TaskHandlerMap`. Instead, if you declare `TaskHandlerMap` as a Spring bean, Spring will ensure that there's a single instance of it. You can then have Spring inject any dependencies into the class and use them to create the map.

Something like this:

```
@Component
class TaskHandlerMap {

    private final Map<String, AbstractItemHandler> handlerMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    @Autowired
    TaskHandlerMap(XXXHandler handler) {
        handlerMap.put(Constants.XXX_PATH, handler);
    }

    public AbstractItemHandler get(String key) {
        return handlerMap.get(key);
    }
}
```